# How to combine two xpath into single xpath

Tags: selenium

[Please find screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8cNB.png)

Xpath Expressions are :
1.xpath

```
//td[.//span='Large' and .//span='Angelfish']
```

2.Xpath

```
//td[.//span='EST-1']
```

Above two xpaths, i want to merge it into single xpath. I tried the below

```
//td[.//span='EST-1' and .//span='Large' and .//span='Angelfish']
```

but no luck. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: what is the objective, what are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: I want the value of table but not complete.only few values need .so i want to merge two xpath

Comment: @Testing Passion, what value do you want? Give some example

Comment: How to add three xpath into single xpath.

Comment: what I understood is, you want to select the cells from the table when any of three xpath matched, is that right? you should check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes correct .if you please help me

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: https://jpetstore.cfapps.io/catalog;UN/pwd:User/user@123.Click on fish image and click on any product id link.Next add to cart.In the shopping cart page,i want item id and product ID using one xpath

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the `JPetStore` site Angelfish table, you can try the below Xpaths :

```
//td[span[text()='Large'] and span[text()='Angelfish']]/preceding::td/a[text()='EST-1']
```

or

```
//td[span[text()='Small'] and span[text()='Angelfish']]/preceding::td/a[text()='EST-2']
```

But I'm not sure what value you need from that because your question is not clear and the given information also not enough.